# Missing Closing, Maximize and Minimize icons when changing Font Family of TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

I am creating a WPF application which is using [ModernWpf](https://github.com/Kinnara/ModernWpf) to style everything. I am also using those two parameter on my window:

```
ui:ThemeManager.RequestedTheme="Dark"
ui:WindowHelper.UseModernWindowStyle="True"
```

It works fine, the window bar is dark now. But as soon as I want to set the Font Family for every TextBlock like that

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
  <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource DefaultFont}" />
</Style>
```

It keeps changing the FontFamily of the ModernWpf Window and the Font doesn't contain the required Icons. Do I have to set a Key and set every TextBlock Style to that key manually or is there another way? Or is it possible to set the Font Family of the window icons?

Thats what the _ [ ] X Buttons look like now:

[image]

Comment: Why are you defining an explicit style for `TextBlock` in the first place? This is probably a bad idea as it will affect *all* `TextBlock` elements in your app.

Comment: yeah but i dont want to define a style tag on every element, i will forget one for sure, or forget it as i define a new one, i have many textblocks in my program, is it maybe possible to define "all textblocks inside a grid with key=..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a bad idea to define an explicit `TextBlock` style in `App.xaml` as it will affect *all* `TextBlock` elements in your app.

Anyway, you can still make the caption button appear as expected if you define a custom `ControlTemplate` for the `TitleBarButton` where you replace the `ContentPresenter` with a `TextBlock`:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomStyle" TargetType="ui:TitleBarButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ui:TitleBarButton">
                <Grid
                    x:Name="RootGrid"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <TextBlock
                        x:Name="Content"
                        Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsActive" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="RootGrid" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=InactiveBackground}" />
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Content" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=InactiveForeground}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="RootGrid" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=HoverBackground}" />
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Content" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=HoverForeground}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="RootGrid" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=PressedBackground}" />
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Content" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=PressedForeground}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="RootGrid" Value="{DynamicResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Content" Value="{DynamicResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You need to set the `TitleBar.ButtonStyle` attached property of all your windows to your custom style, just like you set the `WindowHelper.UseModernWindowStyle`:

```
<Window ... ui:TitleBar.ButtonStyle="{StaticResource CustomStyle}" />
```

Comment: Nice! That's what i searched for :) Thank you!